# Google Sheets (or maybe Zapier) CHANGES my formulas after I close the file and run my Zap:

Tags: google-sheets, zapier

Google Sheets CHANGES my formulas after I close the file and run my Zap:  Three formulas, fairly simple.

All the row references are changing after I close the file (I double-and triple-check the entries before I close it) and run the Zap.

The first formula is: =IF(AND('Quiz One'!C29>0,'Quiz One'!C29<26), 'Quiz One'!A29, " ") it's copied down to Row 1000 (where the row is now 1000 in the formula).  I close the file.

I come back after running my Zapier, which adds a row of data to the worksheet "Quiz One".  That data is supposed to show up on the worksheet where this formula is, but it's not there. Instead, the formula in Row 29 now references Row 30, and all the way down to the bottom, where Row 1000 now references Row 1001.

This was supposed to trigger another Zap which sends the quiz respondent their results report.  But they never get it, because the formulas keep changing...

Comment: OK.  Went back to square one and gave up on Sheets.  Found a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off emailing Zapier support at contact@zapier.com!